# Next Tasks in Jira Dashboard

Tags: jira

I'd like to build a Jira dashboard that allows me to pick the next task easily.

For this, I'd like to order by due date, but for a task that blocks others, the earliest due date of blocked tasks should be used.

Is there a way I can build a query like this? JQL seems to be too limited, do I need a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Swimlanes? That may help. To do so:

- set your board filter to be [ordered by DueDate](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/How-to-Sort-the-Stories-Tasks-by-their-due-date/qaq-p/1315144)
- then, set an upper swimlane for [items that contain linked items](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Agile-questions/Seperating-swimlanes-based-on-linked-issues/qaq-p/1289887)

This way, you'll have all items ordered by dueDate and two swimlanes, one for items that blocks others and a "everything else" swimlane.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly ask for a dashboard, so here we go:

So first you'd need to create a custom filter.

1. Go to Filters -> All filters -> Create filter
2. Show advanced, enter: "ORDER BY due DESC, Flagged ASC"
3. Save as: Be creative :p.
4. Create a dashboard 'My work' or something
5. Edit
6. Use Filter results plugin (or any other that you would like for displaying)
7. Use the filter you just created
8. Save

Kaboom, you're done. Switch the order filter if you prefer flagged issues without due date to be shown first. (I am not sure if all your tickets have due dates, so did an assumption on how I work)

Comment: Not all the tickets have due dates, but if you follow "blocks" (or "parent") relationships (possibly over multiple iterations), you find one ticket that does. The idea is that we can assign a due date to a feature, split that feature into subtasks and subsubtasks (that may have interdependencies), and get a dashboard that shows a list of not-blocked subtasks for the most urgent feature.